# I can create a row, but when an optional property is not NULL, I am unable to read that data

Tags: postgresql, prisma, next.js13, tanstackreact-query

I am working in a Next.JS 13 project with Tanstack Query, Prisma, and Postgres. When I create a row in the `request` table, the `parent_request_id` property is optional. When I create a row with Postman with the `parent_request_id` as NULL, I can fetch all of the rows, and they show in my UI without a problem. However, when I populate `parent_request_id`, I can still fetch the rows, and can `JSON.stringify` the returning array, but cannot read that data in my frontend.

Here is my prisma schema for the `request` table:

```
model Request {
  request_id        String    @id @default(uuid())
  request_text      String
  response_text     String?
  status            String    @default("open")
  created_at        DateTime  @default(now())
  approved          Boolean   @default(false)
  approved_at       DateTime?
  approved_by       String?
  resolved_at       DateTime?
  category_id       String
  priority          String?
  parent_request_id String?

  project       Project @relation(fields: [project_id], references: [project_id])
  project_id    String
  created_by    User    @relation(fields: [created_by_id], references: [user_id])
  created_by_id String
  access_level  Role    @relation(fields: [role_id], references: [role_id])
  role_id       String

  attachments Attachment[]
  versions    Version[]

  @@map("request")
  @@schema("public")
}
```

Here are screenshots of the UI when the requests have a `parent_request_id` of NULL along with the logs from the component showing the data from TanStack Query
[UI showing correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR8Nh.png)
[Logs showing that the data is readable and have loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnayP.png)

Here are screenshots of the UI when the requests have a `parent_request_id` of a string value along with logs showing that the data is not readable, and that the loading component is rendered even though it should only render when `isLoading` is `true`

```
{isLoading ? (
            <tr>
              <Loading />
            </tr>
          ) : (
            filteredRequests?.map((request, i) => (
              <RequestRow
                key={request.request_id}
                open={false}
                request={request}
                index={i}
              />
            ))
          )}
```

[Loading indicator is rendered, even though the isLoading is false from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiDiN.png) 
[Logs showing that the data is in the correct form but unreadable, and isLoading is false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBPgR.png)

Any idea as to how changing a single property would result in different behavior?

TRIED

I tried logging the response at each step, from the custom query hook to the service to the Next.js 13 API route handler.

Restarting the node server and re-migrating the prisma schema.

Adding rows with empty strings and undefined for the `parent_request_id` property, both through Postman/Insomnia and the UI.

Clearing the database and populating first with rows that have a `parent_request_id` of "".

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` inside the component, hook, query function, service, and route handler.

EXPECTED

Rows to return similarly whether the optional `parent_request_id` was NULL or a string value

RESULT

Data when all rows have `parent_request_id` set to NULL returns and is loggable at each step without JSON.stringify, and shows in the UI properly.

Data when any row has `parent_request_id` set to a value returns, but is only loggable with JSON.stringify and breaks the UI logic, including the conditional ternary to render the Loader.